# React Hooks - Map function returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, destructuring

This is pointing to the map function and saying it `can't read property map of undefined`.

ERROR => `return Table.data.map((user) => {`

**CODE**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Table = () => {

 const [data, setData] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {

 setData([...data, getFakeApiData()]);

 }, [data]);


const renderTable = () => {

  return Table.data.map((user) => {

    const { name, email, address, company } = user;

    return (
      <tr key={name}>
          <td>{name}</td>
          <td>{email}</td>
          <td>{address.city}</td>
          <td>{company.name}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  })
 }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your map needs to take the data state you have set and then map the array from there. You then need to alias your map. You can see examples here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Your map function wants to look more like:

```
{data.map(a => (
      <tr key={a.name}>
          <td>{a.name}</td>
          <td>{a.email}</td>
          <td>{a.address.city}</td>
          <td>{a.company.name}</td>
      </tr>
))}
```

You need to make sure you are using your reference (in this case 'a').

You can then place this safely inside a table. for example:

```
export const Table = () => {

const [data, setData] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {

 setData([...data, getFakeApiData()]);

 }, [data]);

 return (
     <div>
       <table>
            <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th>Name</th>
                 <th>Email</th>
                 <th>Company Name</th>
                 <th>Address</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               {data.map(a => (
                  <tr key={a.name}>
                      <td>{a.name}</td>
                      <td>{a.email}</td>
                      <td>{a.address.city}</td>
                      <td>{a.company.name}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
       </table>

     </div>

 )

}
```

This is an example only. But you can see this way should help.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Table` on map statement like `return data.map((user) => {`

```
const renderTable = () => {

  return data.map((user) => {

    const { name, email, address, company } = user;

    return (
      <tr key={name}>
          <td>{name}</td>
          <td>{email}</td>
          <td>{address.city}</td>
          <td>{company.name}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  })
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Table is a function and doesn't have key value pairs. So using the dot notion will return undefined. You are setting your api call inside of `data`, this is what you want to map through. You can access it by saying: `data.map` instead of `Table.data.map`